# Clear left inline element without floating

Tags: css

I have inline elements that I dont want to float. Is there a way of still using CSS like clear: left on inline elements? Thanks

Comment: show me your code demo what exactly do you want............

Comment: could you explain further what are you trying to achieve with a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is no, clear: left; will not work on inline element. You might want to declare element with `display: inline-block` - it might solve whatever issue you have. If you want answer that is not a complete guess, please make a demo on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
span{display:block}
```

usually span inline element.

Comment: I need the element to be inline as it needs to be on the same line as a link, and I want the link text to wrap which one happen if i float everything. Thanks